# RegEx for not matching numeric values starting with 4 up-to 5 digits

Tags: python, regex

I want to match all numeric values except digit starting with 4 up-to 5 digit's 
and I wrote a regex which match numeric starting with 4 up-to 5 digit, but I want to invert this match.

```
c = '475555'
e = (re.search(r'(\A4[0-9]{5})',c).group(0))
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: So you want to get everything that is not matched by this regex as a string? In the given case, an empty string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will do:

```
\b(?!4\d{0,4}\b)\d+\b
```

Idea is to use a negative look ahead to discard numbers that start with `4` and can have further zero to four more digits.

#### **[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wC0QLX/1)**

#### Python code:

```
import re

s = '475555 4 41 412 4123 4123 412345'

print(re.findall(r'\b(?!4\d{0,4}\b)\d+\b', s))
```

#### Prints

```
['475555', '412345']
```

In case you want to match one number at a time as whole string, you can use this regex:

```
^(?!4\d{0,4}$)\d+$
```

#### **[Regex Demo as whole input](https://regex101.com/r/wC0QLX/2)**

Answer (score 0):

Beside the negative lookahead, you could simple "spell out" what you want to have:

```
r'[12356789]\d{0,4}'
```

this will match either from 1 to 9 (no 4 or starting 0) followed by up to 4 more digits.

Example:

```
import re

i = 0
for k in range(1,99999):
    if re.match(r'[12356789]\d{0,4}',str(k)):
        # print(k)
        i += 1

print(i) # 88887
```

It delivers you 88887 matches, because:

```
range(1,99999)   (max excluded)   = 99998 values
4                                 =     1 value
40,41,42, ..., 49                 =    10 values
400,401,402, ..., 499             =   100 values
4000,4001,4002, ..., 4999         =  1000 values
40000,40001,40002, ..., 49999     = 10000 values

99998 - 1 - 10 - 100 - 1000 - 10000 = 88887
```

Comment: Omitting the lower bound value in limiting quantifiers is not advised, best practice is to always use it, even if it is 0.